# converting button into integer

Tags: iphone

I have two buttons, and i had taken one button tag and want to compare with the another button like this,

```
if ([sender tag] != ((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:[self number]]))
```

then the warning is comparison between NSInteger and pointer type is not possible.

so,please help me how to convert pointer to integer,any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, you wanna take buttons tag right?.

Comment: Show me the Code of Comparison.

Comment: if ([sender tag] != ((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:[self number]])) this is the code

Comment: If you have new information about the question, such as sample code, edit your original question rather than putting it in the comments.

Comment: Check my Answer. What you want exactly ?

Comment: @user1904001 see my answer with second option..  here just add .tag for campare both NIIntegerValue see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use bellow code instead of your code...

here you campare `NSInteger` with `UIControl` so you got error.. now try this code....

```
if ([sender tag] != ((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:[self number]]).tag){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
if ([sender tag] != [self number])
```

Answer (score 0):

> if ([sender tag] != ((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:[self
>   number]]))

You are doing the Wrong thing. Trying to compare **tag** (which is an integer) with `UIButton` (which is a view). **How it's possible ?**

If you want to compare tags of UIButton then you just need to do :

```
yourButton1.tag == yourButton2.tag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIButton *btnEdit=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    [btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(NextTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}



-(void)NextTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSString *str=[sender titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    NSArray *ar=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[ar objectAtIndex:1] intValue] inSection:[[ar objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
}
```

From This code you can access the comparison use in to accessing data.